# How to remove partial duplicates from a mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table. How do I remove partial duplicates based on three columns? Is it posibble to apply the changes to the current table? If not what is the solution?

Example:
The current table
Surname.........First Name.......Company Name........Responsibilities.......Column5
McKain...............Christine.........XYZ...............................A................................A
McKain..........    ....Christine   .........XYZ        .............................B...............................   B
Morrell...............  Sally   ..............ABC       ..............................A ...............................A
Motu    ..................Timothy...........    EFG     .............................I  ................................I

The resulting Table:

Surname.........First Name.......Company Name........Responsibilities.......Column5
McKain...............Christine.........XYZ...............................A................................A
Morrell...............  Sally   ..............ABC       ..............................A ...............................A
Motu    ..................Timothy...........    EFG     .............................I  ................................I

and if possible someone please tell me an easy way to add a table here in stack overflow..

Comment: Could you do an example of what you mean with partial duplicate?

Comment: If the combination of the three columns must be unique to avoid 'partial duplicates' - you should assign the three of them together as a unique key (once you get the duplicates out..)     Need example to give you an aswer to your question...

Comment: I suspect it is going to involve an export, a sort, a de-dup and an re-import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace **tableName** with your table's name and the **GROUP BY/UNIQUE INDEX fields** with the fields you want to be unique.

**Warning:**  The GROUP BY used will only select the first entry when removing duplicates.

If something goes wrong, you still have a copy of your original data in **tableName_old**.

```
-- Create a new table that's filtered
CREATE TABLE newTable
    (SELECT * 
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY LastName, FirstName, Company);

-- Add a unique index of the fields you want
ALTER TABLE newTable ADD UNIQUE INDEX ix_unique (LastName, FirstName, Company);

-- Rename the tables around
RENAME TABLE tableName TO tableName_old;
RENAME TABLE newTable TO tableName;
```